# Any java code samples for session management in OSWAP ESAPI?

Tags: java, session, esapi

The documentation provided in ESAPI for Java is [incomplete](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/wiki/esapi4java_v2_OWASP_0300_Session_Management). Does anyone have operational code samples to share for session management?

P.S.: Other code samples explaining where and how to start with ESAPI would be welcome too. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the project is dead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet for examples would be to 1) look at the JUnit tests for the session manangement, and 2) the relevant portions of 'Swingset' (http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java-swingset/) or 'Swingset Interactive' (http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-swingset-interactive/).

That said, the ESAPI dev team knows that most of the ESAPI docs are woefully inadequate and are seeking volunteers to pick in and help make them usable.

-kevin

Comment: Thanks. I did find swingset after a lot of googling. I managed to make it work, but it is far from complete. Hence, I don't believe this framework is production ready. It won't be until proper documentation is made available and evidence of battle testing is becoming visible online.